# Mahout recommendations with metadata related to preference

Tags: mahout

I was planning to write a recommender which treats preferences differently depending contextual information (time the preference was made, device used to make the recommendation, ...)

Within the Mahout in Action book and within the code examples shipped with Mahout I can't seem to find anything related. In some examples to there's metadata (a.k.a content) used to express user or item similarity - but that's *not* what I'm looking for.

I wonder if anyone already made an attempt to do sth similar with Mahout?

---

Edit:

A practical example could be that the current session is done on a mobile device and this should cause a push up (rating*1.1) for all preferences tracked on mobile devices and a drop for preferences tracked differently (rating*0.9).

...

Another example could be that some ratings are collected implicit and others explicit. How would I be able to keep track of this fact without "coding" that directly into the tracked value and how would I be able to use that information when calculating the scores?

Answer (score 1):

I would say one approach is to use the [Rescorer](https://builds.apache.org/job/Mahout-Quality/javadoc/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/recommender/Rescorer.html) class to do just that, but my guess is that this is what you are referring to when you say that's not what you are looking for.

Another approach would be to pre-process the entire data you have to adjust the preferences according to your needs, before using Mahout to generate recommendations.

If you provide some more detail on how you expect to use your data to modify preferences, people here would be able to help even further.

Comment: I hope the examples I added can help to explain the problem a bit more?

Comment: Well, I would say that when you register the preference you just boost up or down the preference indicated by the user based on your needs.

So, if I'm on a mobile and I give a rating of 4.0 to product X, in reality you would register it as 4.4

In Mahout input that would be something like

`98765,654645,4.4`. 

Likewise, if I'm using for example a laptop and I give a rating of 4.0 to product X, in reality you would register it as 3.6.

On the other hand, if what you want is to affect the generated recommendations by boosting or reducing the score, I would suggest to use the Rescorer class.

Comment: The 3.6 / 4.4 stuff is what I meant with "coding directly into the tracked value" ;) ... One thing I think of at the moment is to track everything twice - the first goes into a "generic" preference listing and the second one into context specific ones. Whenever it comes to a recommendation I "just" multiply the generic recommendation scores with the scores for the relevant context. Not sure if that works but that's atm the only thing I can think of.

Comment: I don't know how you would go about that. As far as I remember Mahout only keeps the most recent preference. So if person X had 2 preferences for the same item, Mahout will only keep the latest one it reads.